# Bootstrap navbar button doesn't toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know why the navbar isn't showing when I click on the button. I was looking for a misktake in my code but I couldn't find it. I was comparing codes from Youtube tutorials and with other sources from internet and all are the same like mine. I'm attaching my html code. I'm attaching my code in link below. Thanks for help :)

http://pastie.org/10919972

Comment: It would be nice if you could post a fiddle or a codepen example

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x75e7Lq0/

Comment: Links to code are generally not acceptable. Edit them into the question itself.

Comment: I made my account couple miutes before adding this question and I had some troubles with adding my html code. Next time I'll do my best to add codes to questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Target** is miss-spelled: `data-taget="#example"` should be `data-target="#example"`

Example:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <h3> <a href="#">BrandName</a></h3>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) What a silly mistake. It works perfect :D

Comment: Wow. What a catch. Nice one @vanburen

Comment: Thanks and glad I could help.